# SQLSRV query to array

Tags: php, arrays

I try to query a SQL database and save data into a custom array, but the array always repeats last `row*num` rows on database.

php:

```
class Cst
{
    public $ParagemID;
    public $Designacao;
    public $DecimalDeGrauY;
    public $DecimalDeGrauX;
}

require 'config.php';
$dsn = array( "Database"=>"$database", "UID"=>"$username", "PWD"=>"$password", "LoginTimeout"=> 60);
$db = sqlsrv_connect($server, $dsn);

$sql = "SELECT ParagemID, Designacao, DecimalDeGrauY, DecimalDeGrauX FROM adoParagens WHERE ParagemID >= 20000"; 

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($db, $sql); 

$locations = new Cst();
$location=array();
$i=0;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) 
{ 
    $locations->ParagemID = $row->ParagemID;
    $locations->Designacao = $row->Designacao;
    $locations->DecimalDeGrauY = $row->DecimalDeGrauY;
    $locations->DecimalDeGrauX = $row->DecimalDeGrauX;
    //echo json_encode($locations);

    $location[$i]= $locations;
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($location);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're always working with same instance of that object. Updating it for each row will also update all copies of it, as they are in fact the same object.
Try this instead.

```
...
$location = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt) ) 
{
    $data = array();
    $data['ParagemID'] = $row->ParagemID;
    $data['Designacao'] = $row->Designacao;
    $data['DecimalDeGrauY'] = $row->DecimalDeGrauY;
    $data['DecimalDeGrauX'] = $row->DecimalDeGrauX;

    $location[]= $data;
}
...
```

Comment: that works +/-. when i do `echo json_encode($location);` shows a blank page. for show resultes i need eg:`echo json_encode($location[0]);` but it shows only 1 result

Comment: Updated my example. This way, we're only working with a two-dimensional array. It should be easy to handle when you want to json_encode/decode it.

Comment: `echo json_encode($location);` still shows blank page

Comment: Really? It's not just wrapped inside some hidden div or something? If you do have a valid resultset that is beinged looped through, the $location array should have some items in it. If you echo count($location), how many items does it hold?

Comment: `$location` hold all items (i think), i can only see it with `echo json_encode($location[index]);`

Comment: You can always run a var_dump($location) or print_r($location) to see its whole content. Sounds like there's something messing up with json_encode though. Can you post the first item in $location from a var_dump here so I can test it? Use `echo var_dump( $location[0] );`

Comment: `array(4) { ["ParagemID"]=> int(20001) ["Designacao"]=> string(50) "GONDAR CAFE AVENIDA " ["DecimalDeGrauY"]=> float(41.4157) ["DecimalDeGrauX"]=> float(-8.367426318) }`

Comment: ...and if you json_encode that you get nothing? You should get something like `{"ParagemID":20001,"Designacao":"GONDAR CAFE AVENIDA ","DecimalDeGrauY":41.4157,"DecimalDeGrauX":-8.367426318}` when you run json_encode on that variable. If that index work, but not the whole array - Try iterating all indexes and see which row / index is causing json_encode to break.

Comment: some data on database have accent like `~` or `´` and that data dosnt show on array (shows blank line) can be it that is breaking the `json_encode`? any way to resolve without change database data?

Comment: Are your texts in UTF-8? You can try this this: `json_encode($location, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: the text is in Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: From the manual: "Because json_encode() only deals with utf8, it is often necessary to convert all the string values inside an array to utf8.". (http://se1.php.net/json_encode). Try running a `json_last_error()` after the json_encode to see if it will output any error. Regardless, you should convert your text into UTF-8 before json_encoding it.

Comment: the output of `json_last_error()` is 5. if i use `"CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8"` on connection to database it output 0 and `json_encode` works, but charapter with accent shows `\u00e3`

Comment: Yeah, because your data is still stored as latin-1 in the database. Either update the text to UTF-8 in the database as well, or convert it into utf-8 on the php-side (e.g. by using `iconv`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: the `iconv` should look like `iconv('CP1252','UTF-8', $row->Designacao);`? it convert `\u00e3 (ã)` into `Ã£`

Answer (score 0):

try using a 2 dimensional array.

```
$i=0;

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) 
{ 
$location[$i][$locations->ParagemID/*put your val*/]      = $row->ParagemID;
$location[$i][$locations->Designacao/*put your val*/]     = $row->Designacao;
$location[$i][$locations->DecimalDeGrauY/*put your val*/] = $row->DecimalDeGrauY;
$location[$i][$locations->DecimalDeGrauX/*put your val*/] = $row->DecimalDeGrauX;
//echo json_encode($locations);

   $i++;
```

}

Comment: this get only the value of `DecimalDeGrauX`

Comment: try $location[$i][$j] and check the result once. use echo"<pre>";print_r($location); instead of  echo json_encode($location);